# Как сделать кластеры?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Подскажите, где можно найти руководство по созданию кластеров в python? Ни как не могу найти.

Вот пример: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html

Comment: @nexoma спасибо за первую попавшуюся статью.

Comment: вам нужен пример? добавьте example. да, есть другие средства, приведите их после вашего поиска, пожалуйста,